# an R implementation for Bayesian Networks applied to spatial data

Tags: r, package, spatial, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have been looking into this for a while  now and I cannot seem to find an integrated approach for this. I have some discrete and some continuous variables ( which can be discretized, but ideally I would like to keep them continuous).

I know there is other (some open source) options, however I would like to stick to R, as I am planning on doing statistical analysis.

**QUESTION**: Is there a package (other than `bnspatial`) in R to build Bayesian networks with spatial  data? Ideally with an comprehensive example.

Comment: So what is your question? Please note that questions asking for specific tutorials/references/tools/software libraries are [off-topic here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks for pointing taht out,i have edited the question